# My do while loop does not work, im not sure where I went wrong

Tags: c++

The area that I think needs work is the do while loop because I want it to loop when it only ties. However it also loops when the user wins or loses.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const int ROCK = 1;
const int PAPER = 2;
const int SCISSORS = 3;

int getComputerChoice();
int getUserChoice();
void displayChoice(int);
int winner(int, int);
```

MAIN FUNCTION

```
int main()
{
    int computerChoice,
    userChoice;
    int playAgain;
```

THE DO WHILE LOOP DOES WORK BUT IF I WIN OR LOSE IT STILL LOOPS. I JUST WANT IT TO LOOP IF A TIE OCCURS.

```
    do
    {
        computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
        userChoice = getUserChoice();

        displayChoice(computerChoice);
        playAgain = winner(computerChoice, userChoice);
    } while (playAgain == 1);

    return (0);
}
```

THIS GETS THE COMPUTER CHOICE

```
int getComputerChoice()
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);

    return (rand() % (SCISSORS - ROCK + 1)) + ROCK;
}
```

THIS IS GOOD I THINK

```
int getUserChoice()
{
    int uChoice;
    cout << "Enter your choice of Rock, Paper, Scissors.\n"
         << "(1) For rock, (2) for paper, (3) for scissors: ";
    
    cin >> uChoice; 
    
    while (uChoice < 1 || uChoice > 3)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number between 1 and 3. Try again, thank you.";
        uChoice = getUserChoice();
    }

    return uChoice;
}
```

THIS IS GOOD I THINK.

```
void displayChoice(int computerChoice)
{
    cout << "Computer Choice: ";

    if (computerChoice == 1)
        cout << ROCK;
    else if (computerChoice == 2)
        cout << PAPER;
    else if (computerChoice == 3)
        cout << SCISSORS;

    cout << endl;
}
```

AREA I THINK NEEDS WORK.

```
int winner(int computerChoice, int userChoice) 
{
    int playAgain = 1;
    if (computerChoice == ROCK)
    {
        if (userChoice == SCISSORS)
        {
            cout << " You lose :( (The Rock smashes the Scissors) ";
        }
        else if (userChoice == PAPER)
        {
            cout << "You win! (Paper beats rock) ";
        }
        else if (userChoice == ROCK)
        {
            cout << "Its a tie. Play again.";
            playAgain == 1;
        }
    }
    else if (computerChoice == PAPER)
    {
        if (userChoice == ROCK)
        {
            cout << "You lose :( (Paper wraps rock)";
        }
        else if (userChoice == SCISSORS)
        {
            cout << "You win! (Scissors cuts paper)";
        }
        else if (userChoice == PAPER)
        {
            cout << "Its a tie. Play again.";
            playAgain == 1;
        }
    }
    else if (computerChoice == SCISSORS)
    {
        if (userChoice == ROCK)
        {
            cout << "You Win! (The rock smashes the scissors.)";
        }
        else if (userChoice == PAPER)
        {
            cout << "You lose :(. (Scissors cuts paper.)"; 
        }
        else if (userChoice == SCISSORS)
        {
            cout << "Its a tie. Play again.";
            playAgain == 1;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    return playAgain;
}
```

Comment: Please do not shout. Also, you should try to express your question *before* posting any code. Interspersing text within your code makes both the text and the code harder to read, and it makes it more difficult to copy the code *example*. Finally, the code should be an *example* demonstrating your specific issue, not your entire program (see [mre]). After skimming your question I do not see why the code should be more than a dozen lines, and that's including trivial lines like `}`.

Comment: Three danger signs.   `getUserChoice()` calls itself in the while loop.  Apart from being unnecessary, very easy for that to misbehave.   Also `getComputerChoice()` calls `srand()` every time it is called - `srand()` should only be called exactly once by your program, not every time by some other function that is called repeatedly.    `winner()` does `playAgain == 1` (which as no effect) when you probably intend `playAgain = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Within `winner`, you attempt to update `playAgain` with `playAgain == 0`. But `==` is the **equality operator**. It does not perform assignment. The assignment operator is `=`, i.e. a single equal sign. As a result, `playAgain` is never updated, and `winner()` always returns 1.

To fix, use the assignment operator instead of the equality operator when updating a variable's value.

Comment: Or at least, this was the answer at one point. The question has been modified many times in the 7 minutes since it was posted. Please try to include as much correct information as possible when posting the question. Additionally, please do not write in all CAPS, and try to constrain your future questions to [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. don't post *all* of your code; only post the parts that you've deemed relevant after doing plenty of your own testing and debugging).

Comment: thanks for the input, this is my first time posting so ill try to get better at doing so.